# Route generated by openshift 4.3 does not have https

Tags: openshift

I have switched to Openshift 4.3 from 3.11. I had used ingress in 3.11 and included tls.hosts section to use default certificate from the default namespace so route created would be secured.

```
tls:
- hosts:
    - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secretName: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

but in 4.3 it is not allowed to add this "tls.hosts" section. Then how would I get secured route without this section? Is there a way? Or I have to use routes? 
Ingress in 4.3 is given below

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: test

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - XXXXXXXXXX
  rules:
    - host: >-
        XXXXXXXXXX
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /abc-ui/
            backend:
              serviceName: abc-test-service
              servicePort: 8080
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I am not seeing any error while creating ingress but the route it creates is not secured. Its http://xxxxxx/abc-ui/ not https://xxxxxx/abc-ui/

Comment: Are you creating the certificate using cert manager which creates a secret? 
You're using the `Ingress` object in 4.3 and not a `Route` object?

Comment: I am using Ingress in 4.3. I am not generating any certificate as openshift takes the certificate from openshift-ingress namespace by default.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting, can you update your original question with both the full `Ingress` and the full error message? The [IngressTLS specification](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/rest_api/index.html#ingresstls-v1beta1extensions) allows to specify the `hosts` field. Have you also tried to not specify the `secretName`?

Comment: I have edited question. I have read in the 4.3 openshift doc that tls.hosts section is not needed in 4.3 ingress.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the`termination`stanza:

```
tls:
  termination: edge
```

You have to choose between `edge`,`reencrypt`or`passthrough`

More info [in the official doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/networking/routes/secured-routes.html)

Comment: but this stanza needed in route or ingress?

Comment: in route. This is what make a route secure. If you want to define it in an ingress (it will corrrespond to a route of type edge), you need to add a "secretName" pointing to a secret with the cert in the tls block check the doc. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#types-of-ingress As you are on Openshift, routes are way more flexible

Comment: route vs ingress comparison: https://www.openshift.com/blog/kubernetes-ingress-vs-openshift-route

Comment: so tls section cannot be added to use default tls secret in the ingress openshift 4.3? In 3.11 I added tls stanza in the ingress and it worked fine. Openshift 4.3 has also removed many 3.11 annotations like ingress.bluemix.net/redirect-to-https and ingress.bluemix.net/ssl-services

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an empty tls secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: testsecret-tls
  namespace: default
data:
  tls.crt: ""
  tls.key: ""
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

And assign this secret to your ingress.

```
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - XXXXXXXXXX
      secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
    - host: >-
        XXXXXXXXXX
      http:
.........
```

This works for me